# How do I force amCharts 5 to re-render after I have changed a setting?

Tags: settings, amcharts5

I am working with the `Collapsible Force-Directed Tree` from `amCharts 5`.

In the main settings object I have set `centerStrength: 0.4`.   When using `series.get("centerStrength")` I am able to confirm that this is indeed set to `0.4`.

I then try to alter this setting with `series.set("centerStrength", 0);`.  When I check this again with `series.get("centerStrength")` I can see that the setting has been updated.

However, the setting is not immediately being applied to the canvas.  The only way I have found to make this works is to manually resize the browser window. Only then does the setting take effect.

My assumption is that there is some sort of re-render being triggered when I resize the browser causing my setting to finally be applied.

Does anyone know the proper way to have the settings take effect immediately after being set or knows how to call the re-render function manually?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a way to do it? It's driving me crazy! I keep hitting this problem.

Comment: Nope, still did not solve the problem.  :/